# Can REACT read windows environment variables?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

[image]

Hi guys,

Can REACT read windows environment variables? I know that it wouldn't be best practices and I should be using the .env file but this seems like something I should be able to make my application do and unfortunately all the google is around using the .env file which is how I am going to do it in the end but I would still like to know the answer here.

Thanks guys.

Comment: The browser doesn't provide this information to JavaScript.  (Imagine if any website you visit could read your environment variables...)

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't know anything about environment variables; it's a library that runs in an HTML page in your browser. (HTML and JavaScript don't know anything about environment variables, for that matter, and that's only a good thing.)

The bundler/toolchain you use *may* schlep *some* environment variables over to the JavaScript code, e.g.

- If you're using create-react-app, see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/
- If you're using vite, see https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html
- If you're using Next.js, see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables
- If you're using something else, see that toolchain's documentation.

All of the above-linked tools support reading environment variables from, well, the environment, as well as `.env` files (commonly known as envfiles).